# Partial ordering of functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, order-theory

Let $X$ be the set of all real-valued functions $x$ on the interval $[0,1]$ and let $x \leq y$ mean that $x(t) \leq y(t)$ for all $t \in [0,1]$. Does it define a partial ordering/ total ordering? Does $X$ have maximal elements?

So, to show that $ \leq  $ is a partial ordering on $X$:

i)It's clear that for all $x(t)$ in the interval, $x(t) \leq x(t)$.

ii)$x(t) \leq y(t)$ and $x(t) \geq  y(t)$ implies that $x(t) =y(t)$.

iii)If $x(t) \leq y(t)$ and $y(t) \leq z(t)$ then we get $x(t) \leq z(t)$

How can we show that $\leq$ is a total ordering and what are the maximal elements?
Can we say that the function $g(t) = 1$ is a maximal element? or is it an upper bound?
Edit: I think it's not a total order since we may not able to compare any two elements.

Comment: Can you find functions $x,y$ such that $x\nleq y\wedge y\nleq x$?

Comment: Let's consider the functions $x(t) = t$ and $y(t) = |1-t|$. First one is increasing and other one is decreasing, neither $x \nless y$  not $y \nless x$.

Comment: Yes. Secondly if you start with some function $x$ can you find a function $y$ s.t. $x\leq y\wedge x\neq y$?

Comment: Let $x(t) = t^2 $ and $y(t) = t$. Then $x \leq y$ and $ x \neq y$, right?

Comment: What I really mean is: for *every* function $x$ we can find a function $y$ such that $x\leq y\wedge x\neq y$. How? By prescribing $y(t)=x(t)+1$. This shows that no function $x$ exists that is maximal.

Comment: Hmm, then there is no maximal element or an upper bound for this set?

Comment: My comment is in the understanding that $x:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb R$. Is that the case, or did you mean $x:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$?

Comment: I thought $x : [0,1]  \rightarrow [0,1] $ first. The book does not mention that so I guess it's like the space $C[a,b]$. $x: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
For $\leq$ to be a *total* order, we must be able to order all real-valued functions on $[0,1]$. But what about

$$x(t) = t$$
$$y(t) = 1-t$$

Can we say that $x \leq y$ or that $y \leq x$? Or neither? (What does that mean?)

Answer (score 1):

We can't compare them as we mentioned above, so that it's not a total order:

Let's consider the functions $x(t)=t$ and $y(t)=|1−t|$. First one is increasing and other one is decreasing, neither $x≮y$ nor $y≮x$.

Comment: Please format your answer so that it is self-contained (it makes it easier for the further readers and the comments can be deleted).